# Sequelize associations 2 tables with foreign keys

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm having a problem with sequelize. I need to use a JOIN, but I can't do the relationships. This are my models (User is shrunk, it's really big and the only field I need for this is NR_UTILIZADOR):

```js
var UtilizadoresModel = sequelize.define('UTILIZADORES', {
    NR_UTILIZADOR: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    paranoid: true,
    timestamps: true,
    hooks: {
        beforeCreate: (user, options) => {
            return bcrypt.hash(user.PASSWORD, 10)
                .then(hash => {
                    user.PASSWORD = hash
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    throw new Error()
                })
        },
    },
})

var Validacoes = sequelize.define('VALIDACOES', {
    NR_VALIDACAO: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    NR_VALIDADO: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Utilizadores,
            key: 'NR_UTILIZADOR'
        }
    },
    NR_VALIDADOR: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
            model: Utilizadores,
            key: 'NR_UTILIZADOR'
        }
    },
    DATA_HORA_VALIDACAO: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    ESTADO: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('APROVADO', 'DESAPROVADO'),
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
})
```

I'm doing this:

```js
User.hasMany(Validacoes, {
    foreignKey: 'NR_UTILIZADOR'
})
Validacoes.belongsTo(User)
```

I need to associate NR_VALIDADO and NR_VALIDADOR from Validacoes to NR_UTILIZADOR from Utilizadores.

When I try to execute a findAll with include I get this:

```js
    await User.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'NR_UTILIZADOR',
            'NOME_UTILIZADOR',
            'FREGUESIA',
            'createdAt',
            'NR_VALIDADOR',
        ],
        where: {
            VALIDADO: false,
            deletedAt: {
                [Op.ne]: null
            },
            ESTADO: 'DESAPROVADO'
        },
        order: [
            ['createdAt', 'ASC'],
        ],
        include: [{
            model: Validacoes
        }],
        paranoid: false
    })
```

```
original: error: column VALIDACOES.NR_UTILIZADOR does not exist
```

Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your model definitions the `NR_UTILIZADOR` column is not in `Validacoes` as you try to declare by

```
User.hasMany(Validacoes, {
    foreignKey: 'NR_UTILIZADOR'
})
```

This association definition says that `Validacoes` has `NR_UTILIZADOR` that is linked to `User`.
I suppose you should define associations between `Validacoes` and `User` like this:

```
// you should add an alias to each association 
// to distinguish two links to User from each other
// as well as two Validacoes links.
Validacoes.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'NR_VALIDADO', as: 'Validado' })
Validacoes.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'NR_VALIDADOR', as: 'Validador' })
User.hasMany(Validacoes, { foreignKey: 'NR_VALIDADO', as: 'ValidadoValidacoes' })
User.hasMany(Validacoes, { foreignKey: 'NR_VALIDADOR', as: 'ValidadorValidacoes' })
```

And FINALLY your Sequelize query will look something like this:

```
await User.findAll({
        attributes: [
            'NR_UTILIZADOR',
            'NOME_UTILIZADOR',
            'FREGUESIA',
            'createdAt',
            'NR_VALIDADOR', // this column does not exist in User model
        ],
        where: {
            VALIDADO: false,
            deletedAt: {
                [Op.ne]: null
            },
            ESTADO: 'DESAPROVADO'
        },
        order: [
            ['createdAt', 'ASC'],
        ],
        include: [{
          model: Validacoes,
          as: 'ValidadoValidacoes'
        }, {
          model: Validacoes,
          as: 'ValidadorValidacoes'
        }],
        paranoid: false
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. User and UtilizadoresModel is the same model. User = require('../models/utilizadoresModel'). Doing some of the changes I was able to understand it still doesn't work.

Comment: That matched my edits. I get this error now: original: error: column UTILIZADORES.NR_VALIDADOR does not exist

Comment: You have `NR_VALIDADOR` in attributes that is not belong to the `User` model. I added comment about this in the answer

Comment: That's why I need to do a join. I need to get those fields from table VALIDACOES.

Comment: You can't get one NR_VALIDADOR value for one user record because one User has many VALIDACOES so you can remove `{
          model: Validacoes,
          as: 'ValidadoValidacoes'
        }` from `include` and indicate only one attribute in the remaining `include` with `ValidadorValidacoes`. That way you'll get a `ValidadorValidacoes` array prop in each user with objects having the indicated attribute.

Comment: I believe I already understood the code. I need to use ValidadoValidacoes, if I use ValidadorValidacoes it gives me empty result. I saw the queries from both and compared the queries to understand the result. How can I now add this sub-query to the select? It's another field I need. https://i.imgur.com/gRoOyDM.png

Comment: Just add it as Sequelize.literal in `attributes`